Geoserver clip is giving feature collection, is there anyway to get only count (no. of fetaures)
Geoserver clip is giving feature collection, is there anyway to get only count (no. of fetaures)
Geoserver version 2.19.7

If you use WFS, the standard, and GeoServer, supports option &resulttype=hits.
